# Definition of infinite product of (finite) groups confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, products

I looked up the [definition of an infinite product of (finite) groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Infinite_direct_products) on Wikipedia. It says that the product of the groups $G_i, i\in I$, as a set, is the set of functions
$$
f: I \to \bigcup_{i\in I}G_i
$$
satisfying some things.

My question is, how is the union defined? The union makes sense if the groups are subgroups of some large group, but otherwise I don't understand how this is defined.

Comment: One thing is that the given definition gives simultaneously the definition of products of sets and its group law. I'd find it more natural to define beforehand the product of sets using the set-theoretic union (or assume it's known), and then define the group law on the product when factors are groups.

Comment: @YCor: You now got me interested in knowing what the set-theoretic definition of union is.

Comment: let $J$ be a set. One axiom of ZF says "there exists a set $K$, denoted, such that $\forall x$ $x\in K\Leftrightarrow\exists y\in J:x\in y$". This set is unique (by the extensionality axiom), then denoted $\bigcup J$. Here "$\forall x$" means "for every set $x$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$ is just the set of all $x$ such that $x\in G_i$ for some $i\in I$.  You just literally take all the elements of all the $G_i$ and put them together in one big set.  There is no reason to think that this union has a natural group structure or anything like that, but that's fine; it's just a bare set of elements, and that's all you need in order to be able to talk about functions $I\to \bigcup_{i\in I}G_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I was somehow thinking that the union would be a group.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ordinary union of sets.

One thing of the "some things" your functions should satisfy is that $f(i) \in G_i$. A very clean and useful way to think about this is the following. First, think about a finite set $I = \{1, \dots, n\}$. Then such an $f$ can be described by a tuple $(g_1, \dots, g_n)$, where $f(i) = g_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. This agrees with the standard interpretation of what a product is, doesn't it?

Next, think about $I = \mathbb N$. Then we have practically the same thing, but now our tuple describing our function is an infinite tuple $(g_1, g_2, \dots)$.

Finally, and this is where it kind of gets important that we have a formal notion, if $I$ is uncountable the whole tuple visualization thing breaks down. How does a tuple look like whose indices can be, say, any real number in $\mathbb R$? I don't know. So instead of trying to define what uncountably big tuples are, the disjoint union is used as a hack to get around this.

But honestly, thinking about "uncountably long tuples" probably works in most situations.